# If statement with database values, set different value for each row

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
function duration() {
    if ($row["duration"] == 0) {
        return "Expired";
    } else if ($row["duration"] > -1) {
        return $row["duration"];
    } else {
        return "Unknown Error";
    }
};

    echo '<table>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        timeLeft();
        echo '<tr><td>' . " Left from event: " .  duration() . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
};

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I am trying to replace 0 with "Expired", but with this code it replaces all tables.

Instead of:

```
Left from event: Expired
Left from event: 3
```

I get:

```
Left from event: Expired
Left from event: Expired
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `$row` into the function:

```
function duration(array $row) {
    if ($row["duration"] == 0) {
        return "Expired";
    } else if ($row["duration"] > -1) {
        return $row["duration"];
    } else {
        return "Unknown Error";
    }
}
```

and call it with `duration($row)`

As a full example,

```
$rows = [
    [ 'duration' => 0 ],
    [ 'duration' => 2 ],
    [ 'duration' => 3 ],
    [ 'duration' => 4 ]
];

function duration(array $row) {
    if ($row["duration"] == 0) {
        return "Expired";
    } else if ($row["duration"] > -1) {
        return $row["duration"];
    }
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $duration = duration($row);
    echo "Left from event: {$duration}\n";
}
```

produces

```
Left from event: Expired
Left from event: 2
Left from event: 3
Left from event: 4
```